# C# Service Layer Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, service, tdd, repository

We are looking into creating a new project and are wanting to explore using the Repository and Service layer patterns, the aim to is create loosely coupled code which is fully testable using mock repositories.

Please see below the basic architecture idea.  We will be using interfaces to describe the repositories and inject these into the service layers to remove any dependencies. Then using autofac we will wire up the services at runtime.

```
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    IQueryable<Order> GetAll();
}

public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    public IQueryable<Order> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<Order>().AsQueryable();
    }
}

public class OrderService
{
    private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

    public OrderService(IOrderRepository orderRepository)
    {
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    public IQueryable<Order> GetAll()
    {
        return _orderRepository.GetAll();
    }
}

public class EmailService
{
    public void SendEmails()
    {
        // How do I call the GetAll method from the order serivce
        // I need to inject into the orderService the repository to use
    }
}
```

There are a few questions which we are having trouble finding out the best way forward.

1) Should the service be reproducing the CRUD methods, as it appears we may be reproducing code with no real benefit.  Or should the UI call the repositories directly?

2) What happens when a service needs to call another service.  In our example above if Email Service needs to get all the orders, do we inject the order service into the Email service?

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Email service should not be aware of services like OrderService, you need Mediator to work with both Email&&Order services so they would be decoupled

Comment: What does your order service do? Just encapsulate the OrderRepository? Or does it do more than that, from the looks of your code it just seems like a redundant layer.

Comment: I would ask another question. Is it good to expose IQueryable<T> outside the repository boundary ? For me, not. It's a leaky abstraction.

Comment: @ThomasJaskula IQueryable<T> is completely mockable?

Comment: @gideon yes, but that's not the point

Comment: You might like to take a look at Oren Eini's blog. He has been writing about designing applications to avoid unnecessary abstractions lately, and he has some very good points to make against the use of repository patterns at all. http://ayende.com

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  At the moment the service just calls the repository but from what I've read on-line don't we need keep the UI from accessing the repositories so we can build optional business logic around our methods in the future?

Answer (score 6):

Email service should not be aware of services like OrderService, you need [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) to work with both Email&&Order services so they would be decoupled, or [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to adapt `IOrder` to `IEmail`:

```
IEnumerable<IOrder> orders = orderService.GetAll();

// TODO: Create emails from orders by using OrderToEmailAdaptor
IEnumerable<IEmail> emails = ... 
emailService.SendEmails(emails);

public sealed class EmailService
{
    public void SendEmails(IEnumerable<IEmail> emails)
    {
    }
}
```

**Mediator**:

> Define an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact.
>   Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to
>   each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction
>   independently

**Adapter**:

> The adapter pattern (often referred to as the wrapper pattern or
>   simply a wrapper) is a design pattern that translates one interface
>   for a class into a compatible interface

Comment: +1 By mediator I thought you were referring to the mediator pattern for a sec, but this is correct and simple! :) I don't think an order service is required though, the repository already takes care of decoupling **how** orders are retrieved?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback.  In the example above who would call the SendEmails method?  Wouldn't you still need code somewhere which gets the orders and then calls the email service?

Comment: @user1223218 : this could be a mediator. Considering requirements yu ahve, who is determining when is a time to call `SendEmails()`, is it some event handler?

Comment: Thank you, what are your thoughts on reproducing code so the service layers passes over CRUD commands to the repositories?  If feels redundant but at the same time more open to change in the future.

Comment: @user1223218: see following discussion [CRUD Interface for a Service - Is a bad practice ?](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/01/25/crud-interface-for-a-service-is-a-bad-practice.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Domain Driven Design. DDD moves most of the logic into the entities (`Order`, `Email`) and lets them use the repositories.

> 1) Should the service be reproducing the CRUD methods, as it appears we may be reproducing code with no real benefit. Or should the UI call the repositories directly?

A service in DDD is used when you find yourself writing business logic outside the entities.

> 2) What happens when a service needs to call another service. In our example above if Email Service needs to get all the orders, do we inject the order service into the Email service?

Inject it in the constructor. However, the order service should send an email, not the other way around.

The DDD approach would be to create a `OrderNotificationService` which takes the domain event `OrderCreated` and composes an email which it sends through the `EmailService`

**Update**

You missunderstood me. Duplicated logic is never good. I would not put a method in my service named `GetAll` when my repository has one. Neither would I put that method in my entity either.

Example code:

```
var order = repository.Create(userId);
order.Add(articleId, 2);  
order.Save(); // uses the repository
```

`Order.Send()` should create a domain event that the `OrderNotificationService` can catch.

**Update2**

`Repository.Create` is just a factory method (google `factory method pattern`) to get all domain model creations in one place. It do not do anything in the db (although it could in future versions).

As for order.Save it would use the repository to save all order lines, the order itself or anything else that would be needed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply.  If order was to have methods like Order.GetAll() is this not coupled, how would order know which repository to use?  Thanks

Comment: +1 - OrderNotificationService definitely sounds more like the correct way to me.

Comment: Hi, does repository.Create return an order? If so how does order.Save use the repository.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can use adapter pattern or using DI tools

```
public class EmailService
{
    private IOrderRepository _orderservice = null;

    public EmailService(IOrderService orderservice)
    {
        _orderservice = orderservice;
    }

    public void SendEmails()
    {
        _orderService.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be more reusable to inject email into the order service. You might the also inject it into s shipping service and a receipt service. You should not need to modify email everytime someone else needs to send one.

Answer (score 0):

What I would have done is

1. Not call repositories directly from the UI, but call the service instead and service should use the repository,
2. I would the call the method of Order repository from Email service, this way I would have only inject OrderRepository to Email Service (not Order Service)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, if email service uses the repository directly don't we run the risk of different actions happening as GetAll() may be changed in the service to work differently to GetAll() from the repository.  Thanks